# Power BI Gauge to show number of times a value appears as a percentage

Tags: powerbi, percentage, gauge

I'm new to Power BI and I'd like to create a series of Gauges to show the number of times a value appears in a column as a percentage of the number of records that have been received.

As a working example:

We have officers who go out on-site and inspect the state of equipment, this is then passed back into our system under the "inspection result" field.

The officers can select either

- Good - re-inspect 5 years
- Fair - re-inspect 2 years
- Warning - re-inspect 6 months
- Poor - immediate removal

Sample Data

```
Inspection ID          Inspection Result
123                    Fair
124                    Good
125                    Poor
126                    Poor
127                    Warning
```

What I want to do is use a gauge to show how many values were either "warning" or "poor" as a percentage on the front page of the Power BI report.  Using the data above the gauge would show 60%

Answer (score 0):

Create a new calculated column along the lines of:

```
Quality = IF (Inspections'[Inspection Result] = "Poor" || Inspections'[Inspection Result] = "Warning", "Sub Standard", "Ok")
```

Drop a Donut or Pie Chart on to your canvas. Add the new `Quality` column as the legend and as the value (set it to be the count of Quality).

Use the formatting options to control whether or not a total number, or percentage, or both is displayed.

[image]